# ramifications of chmod 777

Tags: linux, security, permissions, webserver, chmod

I understand what file permission 777 denote. I'm also aware of it's effects in case of shared hosting. I want to know what can go wrong if there is a sub folder having permission 777 in my website and there is one user per machine.

Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777. In this thread, user ImaginaryRobots mentions that if someone is able to upload a file as jpg, he can execute it. How can a file be 'executed' on server?

Comment: What do you mean by one use per machine?

Comment: @xvan: it is not a shared hosting or multiple users on the system.

Answer (score 0):

777 lowers security by allowing exploiting other bugs.

This will only be of concern if you have a dynamic web page instead of a static one.

Dynamic webpages run an executable server side when a client request an specific uri. This executable outputs a binary stream (that may or may not be an html document) that then then is sent by apache back to the client.

The image example is this: a user uploads a php file or a binary with .jpeg extension. If apache is configured to execute php on files with .jpeg extensions (common for dynamically generated images, ie watermarks), or has a horribly configured cgi-bin then the server will execute the .jpeg file when trying to retrieve the image.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this line *If apache is configured to execute php on files with .jpeg extensions (common for dynamically generated images, ie watermarks)*. When and why would data be treated as code?

Comment: "This will only be of concern if you have a dynamic web page" -> Not really. `apache` may also have bugs, and if you have multiple users on you system , or if someone guesses your ssh password, or if there is a problem in another application (like your mail program) it means that those people can now overwrite your HTML files to serve out malware or whatever. Yikes! There is really **never** a need to use `chmod 777`.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html on cgi . For php look for `AddType application/x-httpd-php"`